# How to open/close a modal from my header component in Next.js 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

I am building an e-commerce application with Next.js 13 for fun. I have difficulties when I try to make a Login modal that pops up when I click on a button in `<Header/>` component.

My approach would be make a `useState` in the parent, which is the `rootLayout` here, pass the setter to `<Header/>`, and pass the state to the `modal`.

But my question is, since I will be using useState to toggle the visibility of the modal, I will need to use client component by declaring `"use client"`. But if I use "use client" in my root layout, and use the useState hook here, will it make my whole app `client` component? If that's the case, then this is not ideal. How should I implement it? Is it a bad layout? Should I change it? Thanks.

This is my root layout:

```
import "./globals.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import LoginForm from "@components/LoginForm";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body className="relative">
        <Header />  <-------------------------- THIS IS THE HEADER/NAVBAR COMPONENT
        <main className="p-5">
          <div>{children}</div>
        </main>
        <LoginForm /> <------------------------ THIS IS THE LOGIN MODAL COMPONENT
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```